# draw diamond using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I try to draw a diamond

here a go what i want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9vK.png

consider the red part.

what I want is to draw the diamond using this formula

```
point = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * n * 2) ;
w = 2 * pi / n;
wi = w / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <3; i ++ ) {

    point [i] = (int) (CX + R * cos (wi));
    point [i +1] = (int) (CY + R * sin (wi));
}
```

any ideia ?

Comment: You already seem to have the coordinates, what troubles you at this point?

Comment: the problem is that when I run the code

it forms a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

draw->

```
void drawLine (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
glBegin (GL_LINES);
glVertex2d (x1, y1);
glVertex2d (x2, y2);
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

}

second this

```
  for (int i = 0; i <3; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 3; j ++) {
        drawLine (point [i], point [i +1], point [j], point [j +1]);
    }
}
```

first run this

```
point = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * n * 2) ;
w = 2 * pi / n;
wi = w / 2;
for (int i = 0; i <7; i ++ ) {

    point [i] = (int) (CX + R * cos (wi));
    point [i +1] = (int) (CY + R * sin (wi));


    printf("pointX = %d \n",(int)point[i]);
    printf("pointY = %d \n",(int)point[i+1]);




    wi += w;
}
```

Comment: `glFlush()` will result in a meaningless slowdown here, you should remove it.

Comment: without the flush does not appear nothing

Comment: `glFlush` only has to be called once per frame. It should not be included as part of a primitive drawing procedure.